# Input for developing my android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-emulator

How to take an image as input in the eclipse emulator. The image must be taken from the device camera and the gallery.

Comment: Please help me out how to start up this app in eclipse.

Comment: I wanted all the steps to start up this application in eclipse. From scratch

Comment: Nagging twice in less than two minutes is not the way to make a good impression. In fact, it verges on the downright rude. People here are volunteers. Be patient.

Comment: Im sorry. Did not mean to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register an `<intent-filter>` for the [ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) action so that you can use the standard share mechanism to share the image from the camera or gallery applications to your Activity. Alternatively, you could use the [ACTION_PICK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK) action to bring up an Activity from which to select the data.